# Google BigQuery How to Load custom columns from csv?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a doubleclick csv file with 20 columns (Timestamp,AdvertiserId,ActionName,Brower,OSID ...) without any header. I would like to ingest only first 3 columns into a BQ table. Is there any way to achieve that without mapping each and every column one-by-one manually into BQ's UI (create new_table ->"Schema" section)? 
Fields in CSV is comma separated and newlines are defined as semi-colon';'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BigQuery: Load from CSV, skip columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734650/bigquery-load-from-csv-skip-columns)

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to do that: [BigQuery: Load from CSV, skip columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734650/bigquery-load-from-csv-skip-columns)

In your case I would probably suggest the second approach. Set the [ignoreUnknownValues](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load.ignoreUnknownValues) flag and pass in a schema with just the first three columns. For example:

```
bq load --ignore_unknown_values dataset.new_table gs://path/to/file.csv ~/path/to/schema.json
```